# TypeError: convertDocument() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

I'm try to use Converter class to convert my image file but when I'm use it in OOP it's give me

**TypeError:** convertDocument() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
class Converter:
    def convIMG2JPG(self):

        os.mkdir(inputfile+"\\"+Path(inputfile).stem)

        im = Image.open(inputfile)
        rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
        rgb_im.save(outputdir+"\\"+ Path(inputfile).stem+"\\"+ Path(inputfile).stem + ".jpg")

    def convertDocument(inputfile):
        if(file_extension == ".gif" or file_extension == ".jfif" or file_extension == ".jpeg" or file_extension == ".jpg"
            or file_extension == ".BMP" or file_extension == ".png"):

            convIMG2JPG(inputfile)
```

```
convert = Converter()
input = "/10791227_7168491604.jpg"
convert.convertDocument(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
def convertDocument(inputfile):
    ...
```

to

```
def convertDocument(self, inputfile):
    ...
```

Comment: it's NameError: name 'convIMG2JPG' is not defined

Comment: you need to do `self.convIMG2JPG(inputFile)`. Try reading the errors you are getting and google them.